# Oracle 11gR2 FORALL SAVE EXCEPTIONS on database view not working

Tags: oracle, view, plsql, exception, bulkinsert

I want to take advantage of Oracle bulk DML operation and exception handling. My requirement is to perform DML operation on a database view, where it perform some validations through view trigger, then finally insert/update the underlying table. However, Oracle's FORALL .. SAVE EXCEPTIONS doesn't seem to catch validation error raised in the view. Is this the limitation/restriction of SAVE EXCEPTION where it only work with database table but not view? Oracle documentation doesn't seem to mention this as well. Below are my test codes (based on modification from [Handling Exceptions in Bulk Operations](http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_exceptions.htm)):

Create table:

```
create table exception_test (
  id  number(10) not null
);
```

Create view on the table:

```
create or replace view exception_test_v as
select exception_test.id id
    ,sysdate daytime
from exception_test;
```

Create trigger on the view:

```
create or  replace trigger iud_exception_test
    instead of insert or update or delete on exception_test_v
    for each row
declare

begin
    if inserting then 

        if nvl(:new.id, 0) = 0 then 
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20815, 'ID must not be null!'); 
        end if;

        insert into exception_test (id) values (:new.id);

    end if;    

  end;
/
```

Test code of DML on the database view:

```
declare
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF exception_test_v%ROWTYPE;

  l_tab          t_tab := t_tab();
  l_error_count  NUMBER; 

  ex_dml_errors EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_dml_errors, -24381);
BEGIN
  -- Fill the collection.
  FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last).id := i;
  END LOOP;

  -- Cause a failure.
  l_tab(50).id := NULL;
  l_tab(51).id := NULL; 

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE exception_test';

  -- Perform a bulk operation.
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT INTO exception_test_v (id)
      VALUES (l_tab(i).id);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
      l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
          ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
          ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
      END LOOP;
  END;
END;
```

The test code error out on index 50 from view trigger instead of processing full 100 insertions and catch errors on index 50 and 51 for post inspection.

Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you perform a single test insert into the view and check whether exception is raised ???

Comment: Yes, using my test code above, exception raised is `ORA-20815` from the trigger instead of `ORA-24381` from `SAVE EXCEPTIONS`. Therefore I can't catch exceptions in bulk, because the `FORALL` operation will immediately error out.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the `INSTEAD OF` trigger right now. Let's focus on the `BULK EXCEPTIONS` part. My test case has a table with `ID` as `NOT NULL` column. A view of it. I will use `FORALL INSERT` and try to insert `NULL` values into the `VIEW` via index 50 and 51 in the collection. Expectation is to get the `EXCEPTION` when trying to insert `NULL` in the `VIEW` :

```
SQL> create table exception_test (
  2    ID  NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
  3  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create or replace view exception_test_v as
  2  select exception_test.id id
  3      ,SYSDATE DAYTIME
  4  from exception_test;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF exception_test_v%ROWTYPE;
  3
  4    l_tab          t_tab := t_tab();
  5    l_error_count  NUMBER;
  6
  7    ex_dml_errors EXCEPTION;
  8    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_dml_errors, -24381);
  9  BEGIN
 10    -- Fill the collection.
 11    FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
 12      l_tab.extend;
 13      l_tab(l_tab.last).id := i;
 14    END LOOP;
 15
 16    -- Cause a failure.
 17    l_tab(50).id := NULL;
 18    l_tab(51).id := NULL;
 19
 20    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE exception_test';
 21
 22    -- Perform a bulk operation.
 23    BEGIN
 24      FORALL I IN 1 .. L_TAB.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
 25        INSERT INTO exception_test_v (id)
 26        VALUES (L_TAB(I).ID);
 27    EXCEPTION
 28      WHEN EX_DML_ERRORS THEN
 29      dbms_output.put_line('Inside exception');
 30        l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
 31        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
 32        FOR I IN 1 .. L_ERROR_COUNT LOOP
 33          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i ||
 34            ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
 35            ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
 36        END LOOP;
 37    END;
 38  END;
 39  /
Inside exception
Number of failures: 2
Error: 1 Array Index: 50 Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()
Error: 2 Array Index: 51 Message: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> select count(*) from exception_test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        98
```

So, there you see the `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` has the two errors.

The issue with your test case is that, the code never goes into `EXCEPTION` block. You can try removing `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` and see. The PL/SQL block would execute normally. The error raised due to the triggering event is **not** `24381`, thus the code never goes into the exception block.

Comment: Op check XXX_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS(XXX can be ALL,USER or DBA) for this table to see if ID column is updatable.As i can see from this answer the column is updateable hence INSTEAD OF Trigger is not required    http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. I need the instead of trigger here as I need to perform series of validations before inserting data into the table. The `raise_application_error` in my original post is just an sample which I want to test out to see is `SAVE EXCEPTION` can catch it or not. But seems like `SAVE EXCEPTION` is really only working for direct DML operation related errors (?). I'm trying to look for Oracle documentation to confirm my assumption, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like the below where you catch the exception raised in INSTEAD OF TRIGGER

```
  declare
    TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF exception_test_v%ROWTYPE;

    l_tab          t_tab := t_tab();
    l_error_count  NUMBER; 

    ex_dml_errors EXCEPTION;
    ex_trigger_errors EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_trigger_errors, -20815);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_dml_errors, -24381);
  BEGIN
    -- Fill the collection.
    FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
      l_tab.extend;
      l_tab(l_tab.last).id := i;
    END LOOP;

    -- Cause a failure.
    l_tab(50).id := NULL;
    l_tab(51).id := NULL; 

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE exception_test';

    -- Perform a bulk operation.
    BEGIN
      FORALL i IN l_tab.first .. l_tab.last SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        INSERT INTO exception_test_v (id)
        VALUES (l_tab(i).id);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
        l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
        FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
            ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
            ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
        END LOOP;
        WHEN ex_trigger_errors THEN
        l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
        FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
            ' Array Index captured in instead of trigger: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
            ' Message captured in instead of trigger: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
        END LOOP;
    END;
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using `WHEN OTHERS THEN`, the error is caught on index 50 during `FORALL INSERT` but then the the loop just stop here without proceeding with rest of the `INSERTs`, even `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` is specified.

Comment: Furthermore, if exception `ex_dml_errors -24381` is not raised, then there is no point using `SAVE EXCEPTIONS` as errors are no longer handled in bulk.